# What do you call this behavior of a person in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person is making negative comments and abusing others, but he is not at all explaining why or providing any reason for his comment, completely ignoring the questions.

What is the one word which perfectly defines his behavior?

Comment: What particular aspect of this concerns you? How is making negative comments and not explaining why different than making negative comments and providing an explanation? How is it different from doing *anything* and not providing an explanation? (And how is ignoring a question different from not volunteering information?)

Comment: An explanation will probably allow the receiver to understand his point of view. Or what is it that is actually bothering him/ why is he being negative/abusive. There is a significant difference, I think. Otherwise it appears like "trolling" someone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperious? Someone who is not explaining why or providing any reason for his actions could be seen as **arrogant** while being **domineering** and an absolute bully. Both bolded words are part of its definition.